# (Slightly-) Linear Programming

Tags: python, math, numpy, linear-algebra, linear-programming

I have a linear subspace `S = [v1 v2 v3 v4] = [1 1 1 2]t` where t is some scalar real number.

I want to do a transformation on S based on the following: `[v1 v2 v3 v4] = [A 2A*B 3*C 10]`

What is the quickest way for me to define a new subspace `T = [A B C]` that is a transformation of S with the aforementioned rules?

In this example, the value of `T` is `T = [A B C] = [1 0 1/3]t + [0 1/2 0]`. I get this by finding A, B, and C in terms of v1, v2, v3, and v4 in the transformation rules above. `A = v1` and `B = v2/(2A) = v2/(2*v1)` and `C = v3/3`. Then, I substitute in for the values I find for v1, v2, and v3 in S above. In this case, `A = 1t`, and `B = (1/2)*(v2/v1) = 1/2` and `C = (1/3)t`.

I would like to determine this programmatically in Python. I can't really pursue the change-of-basis transformation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis) because the transformation is not strictly linear.

However, I can guarantee that the transformation only will include scalars and the variables A, B, and C taken to the first power.

Edit: I would prefer that the solution *not* involve a symbolic math toolkit.

Edit2: Along with the simplest way to pursue this, I would also like a solution that can be practically extended to large arrays (1000s of components).

Comment: Can you give an example that's worked out all the way? For instance, in the example in your question, what are you after? Values for A, B, and C? If so, what should they be in this example?

Comment: I'm confused. In your first `eq`, it seems as if `v1` to `v5` are scalars. But based on the rest of the question, it seems as if they are 5-element vectors?

Comment: I've addressed both of your concerns in the edit I recently made. @phant0m, v1 and v5 are scalars throughout. It was my mistake to say they were vectors.

Comment: @David, I have worked out the example all the way.

Comment: What would you do if `T` were 4-dimensional (`[A B C D]`) and you had `v1 = A*B`, `v2 = C*D`, `v3 = 1`, and `v4 = 6`? That would raise a couple of complications: there's no way to separate A from B or C from D, and `v3 = 1` implies `t = 1`, but `v4 = 6` implies `t = 3`. Are there restrictions that keep those from happening?

Comment: @David Yes. The transformation would not be defined in an impossible manner like the one you describe. It would not be arbitrary.

Comment: @Coder Can you tell us what those restrictions are? For example, will each of the relationships for the `v*` values be monomials (e.g., `v1 = A*B` is allowed, but `v1 = A*B + 10` and `v1 = A*B + C*D` are not)?

Comment: @David Yes. Only monomials will be permitted.

Comment: @Coder Would it work for you to take the log of everything so that it becomes linear and then just use a normal change of basis?